# Angular 4/5 input changes not fired

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have a observable candidate list, and for each candidate, i want to display his photo with a child component gallery. But the ngOnChanges is never fired.
Here is the parent html:

```
<div [ngClass]="{'active':i+1===selectedCandidat}" class="tab-pane w3-animate-top" id="#candidate-{{i+1}}"
     *ngFor="let candidate of (application | async)?.candidateList; let i = index;">
  <div class="box box-widget widget-user-2">
    <!-- Add the bg color to the header using any of the bg-* classes -->
    <div class="widget-user-header bg-yellow">
      <div class="widget-user-image">
        <img class="img-bordered-sm" src="{{(candidate)?.dataList | datalist: 'PHOTO.IMAGE': 'image'}}"
             alt="User Avatar">
    <div class="box-footer no-padding">
      <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
        <li>
          <a>Nom
            <span class="pull-right badge bg-aqua">{{(candidate)?.dataList | datalist: "FIRST_NAME"}} </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Prénom
            <span class="pull-right badge bg-green">{{(candidate)?.dataList | datalist: "LAST_NAME"}}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <strong>
    <i class="fa fa-camera fa-lg margin-r-5"></i> Photos</strong>
  <div style="text-align: center">
    **<app-gallery [candidate]="candidate"></app-gallery>**
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.tab-pane -->
```

The ts file of the gallery component is:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  console.log('The candidate changed');
  const key = 'PHOTO.IMAGE';
  if (changes['candidate']) {
    console.log('The candidate changed');
    const value = this.candidate.dataList.find(pair => key === pair.field) ? this.candidate.dataList.find(pair => key === pair.field).value : null;
    this.images = [
      {
        small: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + value,
        medium: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + value,
        big: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + value
      },
    ];
  }
}
```

But this function is never called, i didn't see the log message in console.
Can you help me to find a solution, please?

---

I moved the code from ngOnChanges to ngOnInit:
But candidate is always undefined.

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('gallery images init');
  console.log(this.candidate);
  const key = 'PHOTO.IMAGE';
  // if (changes['candidate']) {
  console.log('The candidate changed');
  const value = this.candidate.dataList.find(pair => key === pair.field) ? this.candidate.dataList.find(pair => key === pair.field).value : null;
  this.images = [
    {
      small: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + value,
      medium: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + value,
      big: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + value
    },
  ];
}
```

---

Here is the code for the parent component:

```
export class NavTabsComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedCandidat: number;
  subscription: Subscription;
  application: Observable<Application>;

  constructor(private consultService: ConsultService, private location: Location) {
    this.subscription = consultService.getApplicationSubject()
    .subscribe((item: Application) => {
      console.log('applicationSubject update');
      console.log(item);
      // Sort the activity list by the last update time
      if (item != null && item.workflow != null && item.workflow.activityList != null) {
        item.workflow.activityList.sort((leftSide, rightSide): number => {
          if (leftSide.lastUpdate < rightSide.lastUpdate) return 1;
          if (leftSide.lastUpdate > rightSide.lastUpdate) return -1;
          return 0;
        });
      }

      this.application = of(item);

      this.selectedCandidat = 1;
    });
  }
```

Comment: `ngOnChanges` is fired only if you are having the changes to `@Input` and `@Output` properties

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with following code:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <app-gallery [candidate]="application.candidateList[i]"></app-gallery>
  </div>
```

**Explanation**
When candidateList[i] will change then ngOnChange will fire. Previously you were not mutating your candidateList array object.
Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you, but i have an error: cannot read property '0' of undefined at Object....

Comment: Can you paste your parent component code. Actually I want to see your data and way to fetching data. This will help me to know about your data and I will able to provide you coorect implementation.

Comment: Hope i Helped you :)

Comment: You can find the code in below. but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnChanges` will never going to fired reason being you are using  `async` pipe ( `let candidate of (application | async)`) which will wait until your data is ready and because of this you always going to have your `[candidate]` input ready, which is not getting changed ... so I suggest you to move your code in `ngOnInit` and it will work just fine.

Try below code in your parent constructor

```
this.application = consultService.getApplicationSubject()
    .map((item: Application) => {

        // Sort the activity list by the last update time
        if (item != null && item.workflow != null && item.workflow.activityList != null) {
            item.workflow.activityList.sort((leftSide, rightSide): number => {
                if (leftSide.lastUpdate < rightSide.lastUpdate) return 1;
                if (leftSide.lastUpdate > rightSide.lastUpdate) return -1;
                return 0;
            });
        }

        return item;

    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this solution, but the candidate is always undefined, do you know why?

Comment: I edited my answer and update constructor of you parent constructor, did you tried this one ? ... I think this should solve the issue,